# Who decides when to hold elections? Any schedule or alert system available?

Tags: support, election

I was wondering who makes the decision when to arrange elections. If there is some plan/schedule, kindly let me know. Is there any alert or reminder system so that we don't miss elections and casting our vote?

Comment: Should we take this as an official notice of your dissatisfaction with the current crop of moderators?

Comment: Voting to reopen - proposed dupe doesn't answer who decides when to hold them

Comment: @CodyGray no since i am exploring stackoverflow i cam across this election thing. Since then I am checking if its election time and its not. So whenever elections are going to help I will get any update in email or alert?

Comment: @Doorknob a new answer has since been added to cover this.